# Partial file name Search of Azure blob storage without file extension

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have image files on azure in Blob container. All files have unique names. I nead to search these image files on name without the extentions. For example i have files:
123.PNG
345.jpg
122.JPG

Present code can search if i give complete name of the file such as 123.PNG.
How to make it work with just passing 123.

Code: ID is being passed as a paramenter which is the file name in blob.:

```
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");
            container.CreateIfNotExists();
            var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(id);
            blockBlob.FetchAttributes();
            byte[] downloadedImage = new byte[blockBlob.Properties.Length];
            blockBlob.DownloadToByteArray(downloadedImage, 0);
            var imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(downloadedImage);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you could do is use the [`ListBlobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azurestorage-8.1.3#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobContainer_ListBlobs_System_String_System_Boolean_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobListingDetails_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_) method that accepts a `string prefix` parameter like this:

```
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");
container.CreateIfNotExists();
var blockBlobs = container.ListBlobs(prefix: "123.").OfType<CloudBlockBlob>();

var blockBlob = blockBlobs.First();
blockBlob.FetchAttributes();
byte[] downloadedImage = new byte[blockBlob.Properties.Length];
blockBlob.DownloadToByteArray(downloadedImage, 0);
var imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(downloadedImage);
```

The above example will find 123.JPG or 123.PNG (or both)

You will get a list of all blobs that have a name starting with the value of `prefix`.

Comment: I am getting an error blockBlob.FetchAttributes(); as blockbob is created as IListBlobItem which does not have fetchattributes() method.

Comment: @PrafulMattoo See edit (added `OfType<CloudBlockBlob>();`)

Comment: @PrafulMattoo Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

For newcomers, you should use like this:

```
var pagesize = 10;    
var resultSegment = blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: "BlobName")
            .AsPages(default, pagesize);

        // Enumerate the blobs returned for each page.
        await foreach (Azure.Page<BlobItem> blobPage in resultSegment)
        {
            foreach (BlobItem blobItem in blobPage.Values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Blob name: {0}", blobItem.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Ref: [MSDN(List blobs with Azure Storage client libraries)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list?tabs=dotnet)